# Merge records depending on first three common columns and place the values which are uncommon in the last column as comma separated

Tags: text-processing, columns, merge

Merge records depending on first three common columns and place the values which are uncommon in the last column as comma separated . I have a requirement to do the following-

**InputFile :**

```
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  AdminServer
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    AdminServer
ABC CommonDomain  resourcebundle  HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain  stringeditor    HelpPortalServer_1 
HWF CommonDomain  javatools       HelpPortalServer_1
```

**Expected Output :**

```
ABC CommonDomain resourcebundle   AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
HWF CommonDomain javatools       AdminServer, HelpPortalServer_1 
HWF CommonDomain stringeditor   AdminServer,HelpPortalServer_1
```

Comment: Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this easily without turning to a higher level scripting language.  If I were doing this I would use PHP and do something like

```
<?php
$infile = fopen("/path/to/input/file.txt", "r");
$outfile = fopen("/path/to/output/file.txt", "w");

$data = array();

while (($buffer = fgets($infile, 4096)) !== false) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $buffer);
    for($i=1; $i<count($parts); $i++) {
        $data[$parts[0]][$parts[$i]=1;
    }
}


foreach($data as $key=>$values) {
    $buffer = "";
    $buffer .= $key.' ';
    foreach(array_keys($values) as $v) {
        buffer .= $v.' ';
    }
    $buffer .= "\n";
    fwrite($outfile, $buffer);
}
fclose($infile);
fclose($outfile);
?>
```